# why memory_order_relaxed performance is the same as memory_order_seq_cst

Tags: c++, c++11

I've created a simple test to check how `std::memory_order_relaxed` is faster than `std::memory_order_seq_cst` value for `atomic<int>` increment. However the performance was the same for both cases.
My compiler: gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
Build arguments: g++ -m64 -O3 main.cpp -std=c++17 -lpthread
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 4 core, 2 thread per core
Test code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

std::atomic<int> cnt = {0};

void run_test_order_relaxed()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; ++n) {
        v.emplace_back([]() {
            for (int n = 0; n < 30000000; ++n) {
                cnt.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            }
        });
    }
    std::cout << "rel: " << cnt.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    for (auto& t : v)
        t.join();
    }

void run_test_order_cst()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; ++n) {
        v.emplace_back([]() {
            for (int n = 0; n < 30000000; ++n) {
                cnt.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            }
        });
    }
    std::cout << "cst: " << cnt.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    for (auto& t : v)
        t.join();
}

void measure_duration(const std::function<void()>& func)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    func();
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout << " duration: " << duration << "ms" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    measure_duration(&run_test_order_relaxed);
    measure_duration(&run_test_order_cst); 
    return 0;
}
```

Why does `std::memory_order_relaxed` and `std::memory_order_seq_cst` always produce almost the same results?
Result:
rel: 2411 duration: 4440ms
cst: 120000164 duration: 4443ms

Comment: On x86 CPUs, there's no difference between relaxed and "normal" atomic operations. You need a more exotic architecture to see the difference - something RISCy

Comment: @IgorTandetnik While many operations are unchanged with relaxed vs normal, the compiler may have access to more optimizations, including reordering, with relaxed atomics. That's not happening here, though. I suggest Kiryl looks at the asm output to see exactly what the compiler is doing, to see if there is any difference between the two loops.

Comment: And for a good explanation of what the x86 chip is doing with atomic operations, see https://spcl.inf.ethz.ch/Publications/.pdf/atomic-bench.pdf.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regardless of the memory order setting, you are requiring an atomic operation in both loops. It turns out that, with x86 processors, which are inherently strongly ordered in most situations, this results in using the same asm codes for each fetch_add: `lock xadd`. This atomic operation on x86 processors is always sequentially consistent, so there are no optimization opportunities here when specifying relaxed memory order.

Using relaxed memory order allows further optimizations of surrounding operations, but your code doesn't provide any further optimization opportunities, so the emitted code is the same. Note that the results may have been different with a weakly-ordered processor (e.g., ARM) or with more data manipulation within the loop (which could offer more reordering opportunities).

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) (my italics):

> std::memory_order specifies how regular, non-atomic memory accesses are to be ordered *around* an atomic operation.

The paper [Memory Models for C/C++ Programmers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.04432.pdf) provides *much* greater detail on this.

As a side note, repeatedly running atomic benchmarks or running them on different x86 processors (even by the same manufacturer) may result in dramatically different results, as the threads might not be distributed across all the cores equally, and cache latencies are affected by whether it is a local core, another core on the same chip, or on another chip. It's also affected by how the particular processor handles potential consistency conflicts. Furthermore, level 1, 2 and 3 caches behave differently, as does ram, so total size of the data set also has significant effects. See [Evaluating the Cost of Atomic Operations on
Modern Architectures](https://spcl.inf.ethz.ch/Publications/.pdf/atomic-bench.pdf).